# update selected list box value in php

Tags: php

I have select option box and also add many field i want to update through submit button.

Here is code:

```
<td><select name="select_provider" id="select_provider">

     <option value="selected">All</option>
     <?php $sql_list_provider=mysql_query("Select opp_provider from  ambition_opp_provider");
     while($cmd=mysql_fetch_array($sql_list_provider)){
     ?>
   <option><?php echo $cmd['opp_provider'];}?></option>

    </select></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update_provider" id="update_provider" value="UPDATE PROVIDER" style="background-color:#000000; color:#fff"/></td>
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Could you add the code that's run when you click on the submit button, too, please?

Comment: and what are we supposed to say? We encourage your work.. :)

Comment: visit the link 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293990/how-to-load-selected-list-items-in-multiple-select-listbox-in-update-view-in-yii

Answer (score 0):

In your code `</option>` is outside the loop that causes to generate invalid html. Simply remove `}` from  and add `<?php } ?>` after `</option>`

And add `value` attribute to `option` tag. `value="<?php echo $cmd['opp_provider'];?>"` and in server-side, you'll be able to access it like: `$_POST['select_provider']` (assume you use post method).

Comment: This code is inside loop i am sending on select box and update button.. i want to which value are selected i can change through submit button..